# SPException: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFF (E_UNEXPECTED) in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, content-type

I've been trying to programmatically copy custom content type and its custom columns from **one web to another**  for some time now, and I always get different errors or exceptions every time.  After yet more tries, I received more strange and cryptic exception from Sharepoint after clicking onto a newly copied custom column in a custom content type.  I checked the logs, and this is what I got:

```
Unknown SPRequest erorr occurred. More information: 0x80070002
Unable to locate the xml-definition for FieldName with FieldId 'guid without braces', exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException...
... at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetGlobalContentTypeXml(String bstrUrl, Int32 type, UInt 32 lcid, Object varIdBytes...
Failed to find the content type schema for ct-1033-0x1000blahblahblahcontenttypeId while caching feature data.
Unknown SPRequest error occurred.  More informationL 0x8000ffff
Unable to locate the xml-definition for CType with SPContentTypeId '0x0100MorecontenttypeId', exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Catastrophic failure(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000FFFF): Catastrophic failure...
... at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetGlobalContentTypeXml(String bstrUrl, Int32 type, UInt 32 lcid, Object varIdBytes...
```

It failed to find quite a few content type schema.  I'm confused with what Sharepoint is trying to do here, and why a simple process of copying a custom content type from one web to another just wouldn't work in contrast to the information found on the web e.g. [this](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/08/copy-content-types.html).

Appreciate any help to get over this problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Content types are defined in XML files that has to reside on the file system (in the 12 hive). If you want to copy a content type from a web application to another, you must make sure that these definitions are also copied.
I would recommend you to install the feature that contains these custom content types on each of your target web applications.

Regards,
M

Comment: I created a custom content type and custom columns via the SharePoint manually, then programmatically copies them to a new web.  Where in the 12 hive can I find them?